# Unable to set cookies using Falcon API and Python

Tags: python, rest, wsgi

I'm trying to develop a user management interface for my project using the following:

- Python 2.7
- falcon 1.4.1
- falcon-cors 1.1.7
- gunicorn 19.9.0

I'm testing the login page in **Google Chrome** initiated by `run` command in **Pycharm Professional**.

**Operating System:** Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

```
import falcon
from falcon_cors import CORS
cors = CORS(allow_all_origins=True,allow_all_headers=True,allow_all_methods=True)

class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Users API'

    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        try:
            data = urlparse.parse_qs(req.stream.read())
            if "loginEmail" in data.keys() and "loginPassword" in data.keys():
                email = data['loginEmail'][0]
                password = data['loginPassword'][0]
                result = self.authenticate(email, password)
                if result["status"]=="Success":
                    resp.set_cookie('session', result["session"],path="/",domain="192.168.32.17:5000",secure=False)
            else:
                raise Exception, "Email or Password not provided"

            if len(result) <= 0:
                raise Exception, 'Empty Response'
            resp.body = json.dumps(result)

        except Exception as e:
            resp.body = json.dumps({'status': 'Error', 'message': e.message, 'details': str(e)})

    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        try:
            data = req.params
            cookies = req.cookies
            if "session" in cookies.keys():
                session = cookies['session']
                result=self.get(session,data)
                if len(result) <= 0:
                    raise Exception, 'Empty Response'
            else:
                raise Exception, "Session Terminated"

            resp.body = json.dumps(result)
        except Exception as e:
            resp.body = json.dumps({'status': 'Error','message': e.message,'details': str(e)})

api = falcon.API(middleware=[cors.middleware])
api.add_route('/user', User())
```

The basic webpage is as given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Project</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body onload="refresh()">
<form method="post" action="http://192.168.32.17:5000/user" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="login-nav">
    <input type="email" name="loginEmail" placeholder="Email address" required>
    <input type="password" name="loginPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button type="submit" id="btnLogin">Sign in</button>
 </form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#login-nav').submit(function(){
            $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(json) {
                refresh()
            }, 'json');
            return false;
       });
    });

   function refresh(){
            $.get("http://192.168.32.17:5000/user",  { 'fields': [ "name", "dp" ] }, function(json) {
                if (json["status"]=="Error"){
                    alert(json["message"])
                }
               else {
                $('#dd-username').text(json["data"]["name"])
                $("#dd-photo").attr("src",json["data"]["dp"])
                }
            }, 'json');
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    function checkCookie() {
        var session = getCookie("session");
        if (session ==null || session==""){
            return false
        }
        else{
            return true
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

On login request I'm getting required response as given below:

```
{"status": "Success", "message": "Session has been created successfully", "session": "F26F75C27942DE27"}
```

But on `refresh()`, I'm getting following response:

```
{"status": "Error", "message": "Session Terminated"}
```

I also tried checking for cookie using `chechCookie()` method above and it returns `false` as well.

I also tried to check for cookies using "**Right Click> Inspect Element > Network**" and "**Right Click> Inspect Element > EditThisCookie**" but found it nowhere.

Then I tried setting the cookie in the browser using javascript by modifying the script above as given below:

```
 $('#login-nav').submit(function(){
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(json) {
        setCookie("session",json["session"])
        refresh()
    }, 'json');
    return false;
  });

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

Using this method, I was able to set cookies in the browser. `checkCookie()` returned `True`. 
I was also able to locate the `session` cookie in **EditThisCookie** plugin of **Google Chrome**.

BUT

When `refresh()` was called, it returned the same response `Session Terminated`.
This means `session` was not found in `req.cookies` on server end.

I have also got re-opened the issue on GitHub as well.
https://github.com/falconry/falcon/issues/947#issuecomment-422652126

[image]

[image]

Comment: At first you should use your browsers debugger to see if the `Cookie` header is properly set in the response.

Comment: How would I do that?
My setup:
gunicorn to run server-side application
a simple HTML form sending a post request to my API route in chrome
I check cookies using this EditThisCookie plugin in chrome or by inspect feature.

Comment: I get response body perfectly but can't find the cookie anywhere. Even check in ```document.cookies``` using javascript.

Comment: Google: `<name of your browser> debugger`

Comment: I have added a screen shot

Comment: I know ```Cookie``` is not being set and that's my problem. Falcon gives a simple method ```resp.set_cookie``` that should work. I'm unable to understand what could go wrong with that?

Comment: Unluckily going with you through the whole debugging process step by step is not a service we can offer on SO. You will have to use a debugger or `print` statements to find out what is going on on your own.

Comment: I used chrome browser debugging and I checked using javascript. Cookie wasn't there.
Using the Postman cookie is created. Looks like chrome is blocking cookies or there is some problem with ajax request.

Comment: You have to check the content of the HTTP response in the `network` tab if the header is set. And BTW: blackening the domain might protect your privacy but might also hide the problem why the cookies is not accepted.

Comment: I notice you're including the port when using set_cookie. Afaik cookies are not port-specific, and I'm wondering if including this is causing it to fail.

Comment: Yep it crossed my mind so I tried setting domain without port as well. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try set cookie like to

```
def handler_app(environ, start_response):
    response_body = b'Works fine'
    status = '200 OK'

    response_headers = [
       ('Content-type', 'text/html'),
       ('Set-Cookie', 'theme=light'),
       ('Set-Cookie': 'sessionToken=abc123; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT')
    ]

    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [response_body]
```

[from gunicorn documentation](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/custom.html)
  , hope this help you !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cookie in falcon like this...

```
class Resource(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        # Set the 'max-age' of the cookie to 10 minutes (600 seconds)
        # and the cookies domain to "example.com"
        resp.set_cookie("my_cookie", "my cookie value",
                        max_age=600, domain="example.com")
```

And get the cookie like this...

```
class Resource(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp):

        cookies = req.cookies

        if "my_cookie" in cookies:
            my_cookie_value = cookies["my_cookie"]
        # ....
```

For more information read falcon docs --> https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.0.1/api/cookies.html